# How to modify the above code to print the circles side by side?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

```
def rating_to_circles(rating):
    circle_size = 9  # adjust as per requirement
    filled_color = Color(0, 0, 0)  # adjust as per requirement
    empty_color = Color(211 / 255, 211 / 255, 211 / 255)  # adjust as per requirement
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    normal_style = styles['Normal']
    circle_list = []
    for i in range(5):
        if i < rating:
            circle = Paragraph('<font size="{}" color="{}">&#9679;</font>'.format(circle_size, filled_color),
                               styles['Normal'])
        else:
            circle = Paragraph('<font size="{}" color="{}">&#9679;</font>'.format(circle_size, empty_color),
                               styles['Normal'])
        circle_list.append(circle)
    return circle_list
```

I want each circle to print side by side. as the circles represent rating. I WANT IT TO PRINT SIDE BY SIDE.

I tried joining with ' ' at the return line. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Here is the working code.

```
def rating_to_circles(rating):
    circle_size = 13  # adjust as per requirement
    filled_color = Color(0.2, 0.745, 0.624)  # adjust as per requirement
    empty_color = Color(211 / 255, 211 / 255, 211 / 255)  # adjust as per requirement
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    normal_style = styles['Normal']
    circle_html = ""
    for i in range(5):
        if i < rating:
            circle_html += '<font size="{}" color="{}">&#9679;</font> '.format(circle_size, filled_color)
        else:
            circle_html += '<font size="{}" color="{}">&#9679;</font> '.format(circle_size, empty_color)
    return circle_html.strip()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what module you're using that defines `Paragraph` etc, but I assume you're generating HTML, in which each paragraph (`<p>`) is going to be rendered on its own line.

If you're supposed to return a list of paragraphs, what you might want to do is try to return a list of *one* paragraph with all five circles in it, rather than a list of five individual paragraphs:

```
def rating_to_circles(rating):
    circle_size = 9  # adjust as per requirement
    filled_color = Color(0, 0, 0)  # adjust as per requirement
    empty_color = Color(211 / 255, 211 / 255, 211 / 255)  # adjust as per requirement
    return [Paragraph(
        ' '.join(
            '<font '
            f'size="{circle_size}" '
            f'color="{filled_color if i < rating else empty_color}" '
            '>&#9679;</font>'
            for i in range(5)
        )
    )]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using ReportLab. Code is working fine now